# Размещение кнопки на картинке в в верхнем правом углу в не зависимости от масштаба страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать чтобы кнопка всегда размещалась в верхнем правом углу картинке в независимости от изменения масштаба страницы?

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas"); // подключаем полотно для отображения кода

var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var image12345 = new Image(); // добавляем картинку 
image12345.src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/08/21/49/lighthouse-3209985_960_720.jpg"; // адрес картинка
image12345.id = 'qwe124';
document.body.appendChild(image12345); // отрисовываем кртинку 

var btn510 = document.createElement('button'); // создание кнопки 

function v52() {
  btn510.id = 'cm51'; // её id 
  btn510.textContent = 'Кнопка'; // её текст
  document.body.appendChild(btn510); // нужно чтобы добавилось 
  btn510.onclick = function() { // функция при клике на неё 
  }
}

v52();
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  /* выравниваем все содержимое body по центру */
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="67"></canvas>
<!-- полотно где отображается код -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но если нужно много таких картинок создавать и чтобы у каждой картинки кнопка была в её верхнем правом углу, обычно нужна такая структура, чтобы прописать это дело на CSS:

```
<style> .relative {position: relative; display:inline-block;} 
             .btn {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0} </style>

<div class="relative">
  <img src="...">
  <button class="btn">Кнопка</button>
</div>
```

Общий блок в позицией relative и внутри неё кнопка с абсолютной позицией, которую можно расположить вообще где угодно, по отношению к родительскому блоку. Через top; left; bottom; right (все они показывают отступ от рамки родителя, в указанном направлении. Могут принимать и отрицательные значения и выйти за рамки).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas"); // подключаем полотно для отображения кода

var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var image12345 = new Image(); // добавляем картинку 
image12345.src = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/08/21/49/lighthouse-3209985_960_720.jpg"; // адрес картинка
image12345.id = 'qwe124';
document.querySelector(".img").appendChild(image12345); // отрисовываем кртинку 

var btn510 = document.createElement('button'); // создание кнопки 

function v52() {
  btn510.style.position = "absolute";
  btn510.style.top = 0;
  btn510.style.right = 0;
  btn510.id = 'cm51'; // её id 
  btn510.textContent = 'Кнопка'; // её текст
  document.querySelector(".img").appendChild(btn510); // нужно чтобы добавилось 
  btn510.onclick = function() { // функция при клике на неё 
  }
}

v52();
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  /* выравниваем все содержимое body по центру */
}

.img {
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="67"></canvas>
<div class="img"></div>
<!-- полотно где отображается код -->
```